# Swift extension: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> to JSON string for URL parameter

Tags: json, swift

Here's a quick extension for `[String: AnyObject]` dictionaries in Swift. The output needs to be in the following format (order and spacing don't matter):

```
{"key": "val", "keywdict": {"anotherKey": 100, "Key2": "Val2"}, "strings": ["string", "another"]}
```

I am wondering if there's a better way, or if this can be improved.

```
extension Dictionary //...

func toJSONString() -> String {
  var pcs = [String]()
  for (key, val) in self {
    var valStr = ""
    if let val = val as? String {
      valStr = "\"\(val)\""
    } else if let val = val as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
      valStr = val.toJSONString() // recursion for nested dictionaries
    } else if let val = val as? Array<String> {
      let tmpStr = "\",\"".join(val)
      valStr = "[\"\(tmpStr)\"]"
    } else if let val = val as? NSNumber {
      valStr = "\(val)"
    }
    pcs.append("\"\(key)\":\(valStr)")
  }
  return "{" + ",".join(pcs) + "}"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Andrew. I hope you get some fine answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dictionary to JSON converter has some serious issues:

- The special characters `"` and `\`in strings are not properly escaped:

  ```
  [ "a\"b" : "c\\d"].toJSONString()
  ```

  produces `"{"a"b":"c\d"}"`, correct would be `{"a\"b":"c\\d"}` 
  (see for example http://json.org).
- Only arrays of strings are implemented, but not arrays of numbers
  or arrays of arrays or dictionaries.
- Value types which are not covered by your code just print as an
  empty string instead of causing an error.
- Boolean values are simply treated as numbers:

  ```
  [ "key" : true].toJSONString()
  ```

  gives `{"key":1}`, correct would be `{"key":true}`

While this could all be fixed, it probably isn't worth the effort
because there is a Foundation class `NSJSONSerialization` which already
does exactly this:

```
var dict : [String: AnyObject] = [:]
dict["a\"b"] = "c\\d"
dict["strings"] = ["string", "another"]
dict["keywdict"] = [ "anotherKey": 100, "Key2": "Val2"]
dict["numbers"] = [ 1, 2, 3]
dict["bools"] = [ true, false]

var error : NSError?
if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: nil, error: &error) {
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    println(jsonString)
} else {
    println("Error in JSON conversion: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Output:

```
{"keywdict":{"anotherKey":100,"Key2":"Val2"},"bools":[true,false],"a\"b":"c\\d","strings":["string","another"],"numbers":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Martin R. For my implementation (which I should have stated) I knew that I only needed to handle [String] arrays and numerics, though I totally goofed on escaping characters! The `NSJSONSerialization` implementation is CLEARLY the better solution, and I totally missed it. Thanks again.